With a sense of humor, just for fun. TeX and 3d printers
Please, do not be too serious.
TeX is the digital version of Gutenbergs typesetting.
Now, how about taking it the other way around?
With TeX and modern 3d printers, it should be possible, to produce ancient matrixes.
Is there something existing like that?

What do you mean by "matrix"?

A printing form, like they are used on printing machines, I do not know the right word. In general, a plate of lead with letters. a printing plate.

Given that it is xmas...
Step 1:
Use latex to generate a .svg with your favourite shapes, for example a cute little duck:
% !TeX program = arara % | txs:///view-log | txs:///view-pdf "?am).pdf"
% arara: latexmk: {
% arara: --> engine: pdflatex,
% arara: --> }
% arara: pdftocairo: { 
% arara: --> format: 'svg',
% arara: --> options: [
% arara: -->    '-svg', '@{getBasename(getOriginalReference())}.svg'
% arara: -->  ]
% arara: --> }
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikzducks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\duck
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Step 2:
Convert the .svg into a 3D cookie cutter with openscad
// modified from https://gist.github.com/aconz2/fa3bce871305f5be39aedd00e7e0c94b

base_height = 6;
upper_height = 2;
wall_thickness = 0.4;
upper_wall_thickness = 1.2;
filepath = "document.svg"; 

module shape(offset_amt=0) {
    offset(offset_amt)
    import(filepath);
}

scale(2){
  difference() {
      union() {
          linear_extrude(height=base_height) shape(wall_thickness);
          translate([0, 0, base_height]) linear_extrude(height=upper_height) shape(upper_wall_thickness);
      }
      translate([0, 0, -1]) linear_extrude(base_height + upper_height + 2) shape();
  }
}


Alternatively, use one of the cookie cutters from https://github.com/TikZlings/cookiecutter

Step 3:
Print the cookie cutters

Step 4:
Bake your cookies. The result should look like these perfect examples provided by @Ulrike Fischer:
https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/66861000#66861000
Step 5:
Put colourful icing on the cookies, arrange them on a tray, make a print by placing a paper on top while the icing is still sticky and then eat the cookies :)

[Nadolig llawen. This is neat. I don't know whether it answers the question because I don't understand the question.]

@cfr
Oh my, could this be clearer?

@cfr Whatever the question might be, eating cookies is always a solution :P

indeed, when chocolate is unavailable, baking biscuits is an excellent solution. when chocolate is available, baking chocolate biscuits is an even better one. in practical terms, I'd advise against your recommended way of creating a print, but if you use rice paper, you can always eat the result if it doesn't work out.

@cfr If you go the chocolate route, you could skip the cookies and directly print letters in chocolate: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mLgk7KkOZ60

This is is the tasty option (and a major reason why I'm thinking of getting a 3d printer) but a more direct answer is possible - people print "rubber" stamps in PLA or more successfully in TPU.  That's something I'd also like to try (or more likely printing a negative mould and casting silicone into it)
